# How to select output monitor to display?

Tags: linux, xlib, xrandr

```
workdir$ xrandr | grep -i connected
DVI-I-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
DP-3 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 267mm
```

from above output we can confirm that I have two monitors connected.

I have wrote small xlib application which displays "hello world" on screen.

Sample Code:
https://www.lemoda.net/c/xlib-text-box/

output comes on one monitor ,but I need to display it on another connected monitor.
    enter code here

Now issue was application always shows the display on DP-3,but I want to show the application on DVI-I-1  monitor,how to do?

I have tried to change input argument of XOpenDisplay but it fails with "could not open display".

Also tried changing the primary monitor status to DVI-I-1 but still it didn't work out

Comment: Try changing the position where the window is created. The code you linked to uses x=1, y=1 which is on DP-3 for you. If you use x=1921, the window should end up on DVI-I-1.

Comment: @UliSchlachter yes right now I am working in same way but I feel it like a work around so posed this question,Thanks for suggestion